Does one have to get an exhaust system that is made for a wooden hood?
We're having our kitchen remodeled.  We had a custom wooden exhaust hood cover made.  We bought a Wolf exhaust system for the hood.  The cabinet maker made the hood too shallow. The exhaust system won’t fit. We can return the exhaust system for another.  Is it true that you have to get an exhaust system that is made for a wooden cover?

You have to get an exhaust system that will fit inside the wood hood. But you need to have a big enough wood hood to satisfy the range/cooktop requirements.
There is a specified area in the range's instruction manual where wood in a hood or overhead cabinet has to be lined by metal when above the range, for fire prevention purposes. Follow those specs when choosing the correct-size hood. (Usually the same width as the range or wider, and 22-24" deep.) Then pick an exhaust system that fits inside that hood size.
Re this:

The cabinet maker made the hood too shallow.

If the plans you signed for approval say the hood is too shallow, then that is on the cabinet maker. They cannot rightly say you bought the wrong exhaust system if you bought it according to the expected hood size on the approved plans and they built the hood wrong.
If they made the hood the correct size according to the plans and you bought too big an exhaust system, then that's on you.

If there’s an attic above, it might be possible to move the bulky air handler up there. Check with the manufacturer, though.

@AloysiusDefenestrate but you still need to line the wood hood with something—ideally stainless steel (although I suppose copper or brass might work OK).  So you'd need to get a custom box made from metal sheet.  Also, putting the air handler in the attic makes it harder to access for cleaning.
